# Where are the logs in composer when creating an Airflow Log

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

This question is not about where the logs of the DAG run are. It is about where composer sends the logs while building the DAG. I use a pattern that uses YAML to set config values so that multiple DAGs can be created that do the same but with different configs.
The sample code is below. However I can never find the output of the logging statements anywhere in composer. the LOGS UI shows only output from Airflow such dag-processor-manager, airflow-webserver, etc.

```
import logging
import os

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.models import Variable
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator

from config_loader import ConfigLoader

SRC_BASE_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
CONFIG_DIR_PATH = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(SRC_BASE_PATH, "", "dag-configs/sample-config"))
EMAIL_FILE_PATH = Variable.get("EMAIL_FILE_PATH")

def create_dag(config):
    EMAIL_FILE_TEMPLATE = config.get('email_file_template', 'email_signature.html')
    logging.INFO(f'I want to know what this values are {EMAIL_FILE_TEMPLATE}, {EMAIL_FILE_PATH}')
    email_file_template_path = os.path.join(EMAIL_FILE_PATH, EMAIL_FILE_TEMPLATE)
    
    dag_args = config["dag_args"]
    dag = DAG(**dag_args)
    with dag:
        echo_task = BashOperator(
            task_id='TEST_SNOWFLAKE_CONNECTION',
            dag=dag,
            bash_command=f"Path to template is {email_file_template_path}"
        )
        echo_task

    return dag

for root, dirpath, files in os.walk(CONFIG_DIR_PATH):
    for filename in files:
        if filename.endswith(".yaml"):
            config = ConfigLoader(os.path.join(root, filename)).get_dag_configs()
            globals()[config["dag_args"]["dag_id"]] = create_dag(config)
```

This is the YAML config file:

```
dag_args:
  dag_id: TEST_DAG
  default_args:
    owner: 'myself'
    start_date: "2023-10-01"
    retries: 2
  schedule_interval: '0 12 5 * *' 
email_file_template: 'email_signature.html'
```